# Having trouble initializing dictonary values in a Python script ported from Perl

Tags: python, perl

I am trying to convert a Perl script to Python. Here is the Perl code:

```
my %ScenarioTenorValues;
my @tenor_list =(12,24,36,48,60,84,120,180,240,300,360);
my $scen;
my $tenor;
for($scen = 1; $scen < 20; $scen += 1) 
{
    print "scen entered $scen \n";
    foreach $tenor (@tenor_list)
    {
        print "tenor entered $tenor \n";
        $ScenarioTenorValues{$scen}{$tenor} = 0;
        print Dumper(\%ScenarioTenorValues);
    } 
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
tenor: 240 $VAR1 = '11'; $VAR2 = { '240' => 0, '84' => 0, '120' => 0, '36' => 0, '12' => 0, '48' => 0, '360' => 0, '60' => 0, '180' => 0, '24' => 0, '300' => 0 };
```

I tried to convert it to Python as follows:

```
scenarioTenorValues = {}
tenor_list =[12,24,36,48,60,84,120,180,240,300,360]
scenario = None
tenor = None
for scenario in range(1,20):
 print "scenario: ",scenario
 for tenor in tenor_list:
   print "tenor entered: ",tenor, "\n"
   scenarioTenorValues[scenario] = { tenor : 0 }
   print (scenarioTenorValues), "\n"
```

However, the output from the Python script doesn't match the output from the Perl script:

```
{1: {360: 0}, 2: {360: 0}, 3: {360: 0}, 4: {360: 0}, 5: {360: 0}, 6: {360: 0}, 7: {360: 0}, 8: {360: 0}, 9: {360: 0}, 10: {360: 0}, 11: {360: 0}, 12: {360: 0}, 13: {360: 0}, 14: {360: 0}, 15: {360: 0}, 16: {360: 0}, 17: {360: 0}, 18: {360: 0}, 19: {36: 0}}
```

Why doesn't the output from the two scripts match?

Comment: The amount of code you've provided won't let anyone reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am new to this website as well. Can you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: thanks. Will do the needful!

Comment: wondering this is more clear???

Comment: You still haven't shown enough code for your question to be answerable.

Comment: is the code okay now??

Comment: You need to use proper code formatting. I've edited your post to make it readable. However, it's still not clear what the *purpose* of the Perl script is. It's hard to help if people don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Your perl code is a little strange.  Are the print statements just for debugging to help tell you where you are?  Why print the data structure at every iteration? You might code that a little more concisely with a map.

Anyway, for a dict of a dict, the setdefault method of dicts is handy for such a case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pprint

scenarioTenorValues = {}
tenor_list = [12,24,36,48,60,84,120,180,240,300,360]

scenario = None
tenor = None

for scenario in range(1,20):
    print "scen: %d" % scenario
    for tenor in tenor_list:
        print "tenor: %d" % tenor
        scenarioTenorValues.setdefault(scenario,{})[tenor] = 0
        pprint.pprint(scenarioTenorValues)
```

Here's a snippet of the perl result using `Data::Dump`:

```
scen entered 2 
tenor entered 12
{
  1 => { 12 => 0, 24 => 0, 28 => 0, 36 => 0, 60 => 0, 84 => 0, 120 => 0, 180 => 0, 240 => 0, 300 => 0, 360 => 0 },
  2 => { 12 => 0 },
}
```

Here's the python version using `pprint`:

```
scen: 2
tenor: 12
{1: {12: 0,
     24: 0,
     36: 0,
     48: 0,
     60: 0,
     84: 0,
     120: 0,
     180: 0,
     240: 0,
     300: 0,
     360: 0},
 2: {12: 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the pythong version, you are wiping out the previous 'tenor' value in the scenario every time you assign the new tenor. I think you want something like:

```
scenarioTenorValues[scenario, tenor] = 0
```